# Log to same file from different scripts?

Tags: python, logging, module

I have a top level `main.py` that calls `core.py`. I'd like both files write to the same long. My code:

File `main.py`:

```
import core

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(ch)

fh = logging.FileHandler("main.log",mode="w")
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(fh)

logger.info("I am in main.")

core.myclass()
```

File `core.py`:

```
import logging
class myclass():
    def __init__(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger("main")
        print(logger)
        logger.debug("Debug message")
        logger.warn("Warning message")
```

From my understanding, the line
`logger = logging.getLogger("main")` should get a reference to the original log, so I need not set it up again. However, the messages from `core.py` are at the default warn level, and are not written to the file.

Any way to maintain the same setup across different modules?

Comment: If `main.py` is the script you are executing, then `__name__` is not `'main'`, but `'__main__'`. Try `logger = logging.getLogger("__main__")` in your class in `core.py`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was not planning on posting my own answer, but I disagree with the other answer, so here we go :)

I do not see the point in creating a *base logging module*. There is already one, it is called `logging`, and in my opinion it is doing a fine job.

The outlined solution in the other answer has a flaw: Although it does create one single logger*, it also creates multiple Handlers and Formatters, one set every time `BaseLogging` is instantiated.

* *Because `__name__` does not change in `BaseLogging`, no matter where you import it from. This is also what breaks the `%(module)s` attribute and calls for 'hacks' with `inspect` to get hold of the caller's module name*

**core.py**

```
from base_logging import BaseLogging

class myclass():
    def __init__(self):
        # just instantiate the class, don't even call any method on it
        blogger = BaseLogging()
```

**main.py**

```
from base_logging import BaseLogging
import core

blog = BaseLogging() # fist instance, one handler and one formatter attached to the logger
core.myclass() # creates the second instance during instantiation
blog.debug("Can I get a sibling, mommy?")
```

*Note: in base_logging.BaseLogging I added `self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` to the initializer to make this work without having to implement methods for `WARNING` and above.*

If you now run `main.py`, your log will look like this:

```
2019-01-16 11:54:23,305:main,DEBUG:Can I get a sibling, mommy?
2019-01-16 11:54:23,305:main,DEBUG:Can I get a sibling, mommy?
```

---

`logging` already works in the global namespace. Loggers you create and configure once are accessible from everywhere in your process. You just need to know which one to ask for. You can check `logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict` anytime and from anywhere to see the currently known loggers.
 *(Note: It should probaly not be considered part of the official API, so I'd rather not use it in production, but I found it useful during development and for debugging)*:

**main.py**

```
[your main.py up to this point]
print("before:", logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict)
#logger.info("I am in main.")

core.myclass()
print("after:", logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict)
```

**core.py**

```
class myclass():
    def __init__(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger("main")
        print("in myclass", logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict)
        #logger.debug("Debug message")
        #logger.warn("Warning message")
```

Output:

```
before: {'__main__': <Logger __main__ (DEBUG)>}
in myclass {'__main__': <Logger __main__ (DEBUG)>, 'main': <Logger main (WARNING)>}
after: {'__main__': <Logger __main__ (DEBUG)>, 'main': <Logger main (WARNING)>}
```

So, all you need to make sure is, that you use the same name if you want to get the same logger, i.e. use `logger = logging.getLogger("__main__")` in this context, or, imho even better, use a dedicated name right from the start, to avoid issues with `__name__` having different values based on whether the script is executed or imported.

**main.py**

```
[...]
logger = logging.getLogger("main_logger")
[...]
```

**core.py**

```
# in myclass.__init__()
[...]
logger = logging.getLogger("main_logger")
[...]
```

=> **main.log**

```
I am in main.
Debug message
Warning message
```

Comment: Thanks! I landed up implementing this. To get the name of the module or the function that the message is coming from, I used the `formatter` keywords `funcName` and `module`. Much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The best idea will be to create a base logging module and to import it and use it in all of your files.

A sample will be as below

```
class BaseLogging():

    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        self.formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(mod_name)s,%(levelname)s:%(message)s')
        self.file_handler = logging.FileHandler('debug.log')
        self.file_handler.setFormatter(self.formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(self.file_handler)

    def debug(self, msg):
        module_stack = inspect.stack()[1][1]
        mod_name = inspect.getmodulename(module_stack)
        d = {'mod_name': mod_name}
        self.logger.debug(msg, extra=d)
```

> I have only shown the code for debug here, but similarily you can
>   write methods for warning, critical and all.

Then just import this BaseLogging to your required module and you can easily log your messages. The logger will write all the log messages into a single file and will also indicate the module from which the log entry is written.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to avoid creating a new class for this.